# PHP: single cronjob with current hour condition for sending several different e-mails

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have several types of automated e-mails to be sent programmatically to users in my database. The amount will change but the times for execution are :00 sharp.

So instead of setting different cron jobs to be executed in different hours of the day I was thinking to create only a single script to run hourly, which checks the time and sends e-mails accordingly. Here's the rough idea:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
// setting the timezone to the one of the hosting server
$cur_hour = (int)date('G'); // PDT hour

if ($cur_hour == 1) { // 1am

    // collect information from db
    // send e-mail A to these users
    // update db

} elseif ($cur_hour == 2) { // 2am

    // collect information from db
    // send e-mail B to these users
    // update db

} elseif ($cur_hour == 3) { // 3am

    // likewise…

}
```

Is this the right approach or is there a more efficient or a better way to do this?

**Additional info:**
There are variables in some e-mails so I can't send a single e-mail there. I will need to send e.g. *e-mail A* to each applicable user separately. And there are not thousands of users yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would have an array of strings (templates) that can include things like `$username` etc in them. Select the appropriate string from the array based upon the hour. Use `eval` to construct the email message for that user.

Despite what people say, this is a good use of `eval`. It is safe as the string is under your control. Just ensure that the variables have been sanitized (but as a good programmer you would do that before putting them in the database, or escape them).

Comment: The thing is, my variables are not "Dear [name] [surname]" to be sent to the [email] variable. I have, for example, something like "You have **N1 new notifications** in the last **N2**" where N1 is an integer and N2 is another integer, which becomes `24 hours`,`3 days`,`week`,`2 weeks` or `month` depending on the notification e-mail frequency preference of that specific user.

Comment: Why not just convert those integers to a string in the format before construct the email message?

Comment: I'm already doing that but the case is, each e-mail takes different amount of variables with different values. Anyway I'm actually trying to figure out if checking time and executing different scripts accordingly using if conditions (like in my example code) is the right way to go.

Comment: @inhan - Why not just have 24 cron scripts (they may be the same script with different parameters). It is a one off job to edit `crontab`

Comment: @inham - There exists a set of strings that you can use in your templates. Some could be empty.

Comment: Still not answering my question here. Thanks for your efford anyway.

Comment: @inhan - What is the question?